# Why is \Cline increasing the font size in my equations?

Tags: equations, fontsize

**The Problem**

When I use `\Cline` to underline a symbol in my equation, it increases the font size of that symbol. Edit: I don't want this to happen, rather, I would like all of my subscripts to be the same size, regardless of whether they are underlined or not.

**Minimum Working Example**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\newsavebox\MBox
\newcommand\Cline[2][red]{{\sbox\MBox{$#2$}%
\rlap{\usebox\MBox}\color{#1}\rule[-1.2\dp\MBox]{\wd\MBox}{0.85pt}}}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}    
\bar{\nabla}_{\!\mu}h_{\Cline{\rho\sigma}}
\end{equation}    
\end{document}
```

**Edit - Follow-up Question: The Cherry on the Cake**

Would it be possible to achieve the right-hand-side of the following image?

[image]

At the moment, egreg's code (see below) will give the left-hand-side output for the code

```
\begin{equation}
\bar{R}_{\tau\Cline{\sigma}\nu\Cline{\rho}}
\end{equation}
```

This is a marked improvement on the look to the output of the MWE above. However, I think it looks nicer if all the `Cline` lines are 'at the same level to the eye'.

Comment: You're basically using a construction with `\mbox` that uses by default the main text font size.

Comment: Pardon me, I forgot to ask the *actual* question, which is "how can I change the font size of the underlined symbol to match that of the other subscripts?"

Comment: For the "cherry" problem you need to say `\Cline{\vphantom{\rho}\sigma}`. I'm not sure if the result is really better.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can exploit `\text` that will do the right font size selection:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\newsavebox\MBox
\newcommand\Cline[2][red]{%
  \text{% We use \text so the size will be the right one
        \sbox\MBox{$#2$}% We typeset the argument
        \rlap{\color{#1}\rule[-\dimexpr\dp\MBox+1pt\relax]{\wd\MBox}{0.85pt}}% the rule
        \usebox{\MBox}% the text
        }% end of \text
}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\bar{\nabla}_{\!\mu}h_{\Cline{\rho\sigma}}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

By setting the depth of the rule with `\dimexpr` we can be sure that the text will not be overwritten, because there will be 0.15pt between the text and the rule.

[image]

---

A different implementation without doing any measurement:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\newcommand{\Cline}[2][red]{%
  \text{%                
    \oalign{$#2$\cr\color{#1}\leaders\hrule height 0.85pt\hfil\cr}%
  }%
}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\bar{\nabla}_{\!\mu}h_{\Cline{\rho\sigma}}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

You can adjust the vertical spacing between text and rule by adding a suitable

```
\noalign{\vskip-??pt}
```

(where `??` is some number) just after the first `\cr`.

[image]

---

Using a fixed rule thickness can be viewed as wrong; so here's a different specification:

```
\newcommand{\Cline}[2][red]{%
  \text{%
    \oalign{$#2$\cr\color{#1}\leaders\hrule height 0.2ex\hfil\cr}%
  }%
}
```

At 10pt size, 0.2ex is 0.86pt, so this is the same as your setting; but this will be slightly less in subscripts; with

```
\begin{equation}
\bar{\nabla}_{\!\mu}h_{\Cline{\sigma}}\Cline{aaa}
\end{equation}
```

we would get the preferable<sup>1</sup> output

[image]

<sup>1</sup> Thanks to David Carlisle for insisting in recommending this variable thickness as preferable.

Comment: ah I was all ready to post a `\mathpallete` version as well:-( shouldn't that .85pt be .085em (which is a bit easier using `\text` than using \mathpallete as the em size will change)